# Is it possible to get data about specific game from Epic Games Store?

Tags: rest

I am trying to get data (title, publisher, release date etc.) about specific game from Epic Games Store via REST. I tried to look for answers in their Dev documentation, but I only found information about publishing your own game there. I found similar API solution for other game shops, but I still cannot figure it out with EGS? Is it possible to do at all?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible you can use epicstore_api here is the [dcumentation](https://epicstore-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#api-wrapper).  you can use fetch_store_games() with keywords="game name" it will give you the data about the specific game

Answer (score 1):

I reverse engineered the unofficial python plugin and found out about the Graph hql api for the epic game store.I think its the best way to access information from the EGS .  here is an example of a https request

```
    https://graphql.epicgames.com/graphql?query=query searchStoreQuery(
  $allowCountries: String
  $category: String
  $namespace: String
  $itemNs: String
  $sortBy: String
  $sortDir: String
  $start: Int
  $tag: String
  $releaseDate: String
  $withPrice: Boolean = true
) {
  Catalog {
    searchStore(
      allowCountries: $allowCountries
      category: $category
      count: 1
      country: "US"
      keywords: "celeste"
      namespace: $namespace
      itemNs: $itemNs
      sortBy: $sortBy
      sortDir: $sortDir
      releaseDate: $releaseDate
      start: $start
      tag: $tag
    ) {
      elements {
        title
        description
        keyImages {
          type
          url
        }
        seller {
          name
        }
        categories {
          path
        }
        price(country: "US") @include(if: $withPrice) {
          totalPrice {
            fmtPrice(locale: "en-US") {              
              discountPrice             
            }
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can adjust it to suit your needs , here is a more complicated request

```
{'count': 1, 'category': 'engines|games|bundles', 'allowCountries': 'US', 'namespace': '', 'sortBy': 'title', 'sortDir': 'ASC', 'releaseDate': None, 'start': 0, 'keywords': 'celeste', 'tag': '', 'withPrice': True, 'locale': 'en-US', 'country': 'US'}
https://graphql.epicgames.com/graphql?query=query searchStoreQuery($allowCountries: String, $category: String, $count: Int, $country: String!, $keywords: String, $locale: String, $namespace: String, $itemNs: String, $sortBy: String, $sortDir: String, $start: Int, $tag: String, $releaseDate: String, $withPrice: Boolean = false, $withPromotions: Boolean = false) {
  Catalog {
    searchStore(allowCountries: $allowCountries, category: $category, count: $count, country: $country, keywords: $keywords, locale: $locale, namespace: $namespace, itemNs: $itemNs, sortBy: $sortBy, sortDir: $sortDir, releaseDate: $releaseDate, start: $start, tag: $tag) {
      elements {
        title
        id
        namespace
        description
        effectiveDate
        keyImages {
          type
          url
        }
        seller {
          id
          name
        }
        productSlug
        urlSlug
        url
        tags {
          id
        }
        items {
          id
          namespace
        }
        customAttributes {
          key
          value
        }
        categories {
          path
        }
        price(country: $country) @include(if: $withPrice) {
          totalPrice {
            discountPrice
            originalPrice
            voucherDiscount
            discount
            currencyCode
            currencyInfo {
              decimals
            }
            fmtPrice(locale: $locale) {
              originalPrice
              discountPrice
              intermediatePrice
            }
          }
          lineOffers {
            appliedRules {
              id
              endDate
              discountSetting {
                discountType
              }
            }
          }
        }
        promotions(category: $category) @include(if: $withPromotions) {
          promotionalOffers {
            promotionalOffers {
              startDate
              endDate
              discountSetting {
                discountType
                discountPercentage
              }
            }
          }
          upcomingPromotionalOffers {
            promotionalOffers {
              startDate
              endDate
              discountSetting {
                discountType
                discountPercentage
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      paging {
        count
        total
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps , cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Try to go to Epic Games in the browser and find the game you need. Next, you will have to load the html of this page using the HtmlAgilityPack library.
To find the information you need about this game, you need to hover over the information you need, press right click and look at the page code. Then, also through the HtmlAgilityPack library, unload the information you need into a variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).